# unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm a GSuite Administrator with nearly 300 users and I'm migrating away from GSuite. I need to download all our user files they've created/uploaded.

I'm starting small with writing a Python script that will show me user files in a list and seems like I'm stuck with the overwhelming authorization issues.

1. I've created a project in Google Console, and created a Service Account with private key (json based) and GSuite Domain-wide delegation checkbox ticked
2. In my GSuite Admin panel I've added the newly created client ID and permission scope in Manage API access to these scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.datatransfer,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group`

So good according to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

3. I'm creating a resource object from the ServiceAccountCredentials and building an object based off API name/version "drive" and "v3" respectively and trying to get files list according to Google's quickstart (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python):

   ```
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "drive-getter@mygoogledomain.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12 = "./service_key.json"

    def create_directory_service(user_email):
      credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
      credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

      return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)


    resource = create_directory_service('username@mydomain.com')

    results = resource.files().list(
      pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    ).execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])

    print(items)
   ```

It looks totally correct, but I get this error message:

> Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.5087.37)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line
>   1664, in 
>       main()   File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line
>   1658, in main
>       globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py",
>   line 1068, in run
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File
>   "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py",
>   line 18, in execfile
>       exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "/Users/probe/Projects/drive_getter/src/dconnect.py", line 16, in
>   
>       pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)"   File "/Users/probe/Projects/drive_getter/drive_getter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py",
>   line 130, in positional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/probe/Projects/drive_getter/drive_getter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py",
>   line 835, in execute
>       method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)   File
>   "/Users/probe/Projects/drive_getter/drive_getter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py",
>   line 162, in _retry_request
>       resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/probe/Projects/drive_getter/drive_getter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py",
>   line 159, in new_request
>       credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)   File "/Users/probe/Projects/drive_getter/drive_getter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py",
>   line 749, in _refresh
>       self._do_refresh_request(http)   File "/Users/probe/Projects/drive_getter/drive_getter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py",
>   line 819, in _do_refresh_request
>       raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status) oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client:
>   Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.

Any idea what was done wrong in the process? Again - My goal is to list and later download all user files from all GSuite users, so I was thinking of looping my user emails and applying the same logic to all of them until I get all the files downloaded.

Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: can you try with `fields="files(id, name)"` this much only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was simple.

First of all, to what I could find, google.oauth2 library supports domain wide delegation functions only if you use P12 key and construct an object based on these credentials.

Second, please pay attention to the filename of p12 key you are downloading, I was renaming the key filename to something shorter and didn't pay attention that Google includes public key fingerprint in the filename itself.

So the solution is, all the steps described in my question post, create service account with p12 key, tick domain wide delegation, and the working code would look like this:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "client-name@client-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
PK12_FILE = "./private-key-original-filename.p12"
PK12_PASSWORD = "notasecret"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def create_directory_service(user_email):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        PK12_FILE,
        PK12_PASSWORD,
        scopes=SCOPES
    )

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)


bryan = create_directory_service('domain-user@your-domain.com')

results = bryan.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, parents)"
).execute()

items = results.get('files', [])

print(items)
```

Bonus: If you'd ever want to download files from GDrive and preserve folder structure (Google doesn't tell you whether a file hash is a folder or not), use mimeType extracted and parent ID to build a stack of parents (folders), create them automatically while looping your list and then place the files within their respective parent ID.

Comment: *google.oauth2 library supports domain wide delegation functions only if you use P12 key*   if that's true its a bug and you should log it on the issue forums its not something I have heard of before

Comment: If I try this, I get "This library only implements PKCS#12 support via the pyOpenSSL library.
Either install pyOpenSSL, or please convert the .p12 file
to .pem format " even though I have pyOpenSSL installed...?

Answer (score 5):

> Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.

There are sevral diffrent types of clients in Google Develoepr console.

- Browser - Used for web applications.
- Native  - used for installed applications
- Service account  - used for server to server communication
- Mobile

The code used to authenticate with these different types is understandably different.

The code you are using appears to be the correct code for a python with a service account. Although `from_json_keyfile_name` accepts a p12 file and not a .json file.

There for the client must be in corect.  Go back to Google developer console create a service account client and download the correct .json file.

[Service account python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts)

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

I recommend using the .json file over the p12 file i suspect google will discontinue using these at some point in the future.

Comment: There's a problem. If I import `from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials` it has credentials.create_delegated method which allows me to download files of specific user, but this object doesn't support service account credentials in JSON, but when I use your import, i can load service account credentials in JSON, but there's no create_delegated method. :)

Comment: @deb0rian so what's the solution?